# Use app URL provided in Jenkins string parameter

Tags: jenkins

My selenium scripts open up "Browser & URL" combination that's parameterized in my properties file.
I also have a Jenkins Job to run above selenium scripts.
I'd like Jenkins Job to pick up app URL from string parameter provided with in Jenkins, so I can select my choice of URL at runtime.
Can't seem to figure out a way to do that, Any ideas?
My Goals & Options in Jenkins are set to:- 
clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=SpecApp -Dappurl=${SpecApp URL} -Dcucumber.options=${tags}

Comment: Are you trying to do that via pipeline script?

Comment: No, it's a normal Jenkins job.

Comment: In that case you can just get values dynamically using the parameters and use them directly in your pipeline. Like below.
parameters {
  string defaultValue: 'Chrome', description: '', name: 'Browser', trim: true
  string defaultValue: 'https://localhost:8080', description: 'URL to launch', name: 'URL', trim: true
}
environment {
URL="${URL}"
Browser="${Browser}"
}

You can just call these variables any where in your pipeline script then.